# How to use groupby agg and rename functions for all columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

#### Question

***How do I get the following result without having to assign a function dictionary for every column?***

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg({'one': {'SUM': 'sum', 'HowMany': 'count'},
                         'two': {'SUM': 'sum', 'HowMany': 'count'}})
```

[image]

#### What I've done so far

Consider the `df`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], ['One', 'Two']],
                                 names=['Alpha', 'Numeric'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(8).reshape(4, 2), idx, ['one', 'two'])

df
```

[image]

I want to use `groupby().agg()` where I run the set of functions and rename their output columns.

This works fine.

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg({'one': {'SUM': 'sum', 'HowMany': 'count'}})
```

[image]

But I want to do this for all columns.  I could do this:

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg(['sum', 'count'])
```

[image]

But I'm missing the great renaming I've done.  I'd hoped that this would work:

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg({'SUM': 'sum', 'HowMany': 'count'})
```

But it doesn't.  I get this error:

> ```
> KeyError: 'SUM'
> ```

This makes sense.  Pandas is looking at the keys of the passed dictionary for columns names.  It's how I got the example at the start to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is using `.rename()` an option for you?

```
In [7]: df.groupby(level=0).agg(['sum', 'count']).rename(columns=dict(sum='SUM', count='HowMany'))
Out[7]:
      one         two
      SUM HowMany SUM HowMany
Alpha
A       2       2   4       2
B      10       2  12       2
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `set_levels`:

```
g = df.groupby(level=0).agg(['sum', 'count'])
g.columns.set_levels(['SUM', 'HowMany'], 1, inplace=True)
g
>>>
      one         two
      SUM HowMany SUM HowMany
Alpha
A       2       2   4       2
B      10       2  12       2
```

Comment: This was a really good answer.  I had a difficult time choosing ;-)

Comment: MaxU wins for pithiness :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is an ugly answer:

```
gb = df.stack(0).groupby(level=[0, -1])
df1 = gb.agg({'SUM': 'sum', 'HowMany': 'count'})
df1.unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1, 0)
```

[image]